# Python dicts in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I would like to load/save a dict to/from my sqlite DB, but am having some problems figuring out a simple way to do it. I don't really need to be able to filter, etc., based on the contents so a simple conversion to/from string is fine.

The next-best thing would be foreign keys. Please don't post links to huge examples, my head would explode if I ever set eyes on any those.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a custom type by subclassing `sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator` to handle serialization and deserialization to Text.

An implementation might look like

```
import json
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator

SIZE = 256

class TextPickleType(TypeDecorator):

    impl = sqlalchemy.Text(SIZE)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value)

        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.loads(value)
        return value
```

Example usage:

```
class SomeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'the_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    json_field = Column(TextPickleType())

s = SomeModel(json_field={'baked': 'beans', 'spam': 'ham'})
session.add(s)
session.commit()
```

This is outlined in [an example in the SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html#establishing-mutability-on-scalar-column-values), which also shows how to track mutations of that dictionary.

This approach should work for all versions of Python, whereas simply passing `json` as the value to the `pickler` argument of `PickleType` will not work correctly, as [AlexGrönholm points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378325/python-dicts-in-sqlalchemy#comment70099307_1378818) in his comment on another answer.

Comment: Your answer is not complete, so can't accept. It also has references to "the accepted answer" which deflects any attempt and changing that particular state on any answer. Please instad start with a correct answer, and (if you must) include what others have done wrong at the end.

Comment: @JonasByström fair enough, I've removed the reference to the currently accepted answer and extended the example a bit

Comment: This worked when I first set it up. However after adding a new field to my model(`product_count = db.Column(db.Integer)`) it gives me the following error when migrating the changes to mysql: `NameError: name 'TextPickleType' is not defined`

Comment: Assuming you're migrating with alembic, you probably have to import that type in your migration script. Hard to tell.  Maybe ask a new question?

Answer (score 66):

The SQLAlchemy [PickleType](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType) is meant exactly for this.

```
class SomeEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_entity'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    attributes = Column(PickleType)

# Just set the attribute to save it
s = SomeEntity(attributes={'baked': 'beans', 'spam': 'ham'})
session.add(s)
session.commit()

# If mutable=True on PickleType (the default) SQLAlchemy automatically
# notices modifications.
s.attributes['parrot'] = 'dead'
session.commit()
```

You can change the serialization mechanism by changing out the pickler with something else that has `dumps()` and `loads()` methods. The underlying storage mechanism by subclassing PickleType and overriding the impl attritbute:

```
class TextPickleType(PickleType):
    impl = Text

import json
class SomeOtherEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_other_entity'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    attributes = Column(TextPickleType(pickler=json))
```

Comment: Lovely! I'll try it out first thing monday.

Comment: I'm probably doing something seriously wrong when I try     self._properties[k] = v? I get "TypeError: 'Column' object does not support item assignment".

Comment: My example was with the declarative syntax for defining tables and mappers in one shot. The error you have sounds like you haven't used the declarative base class for your classes. To do this add Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base() before your class definitions.

Comment: just want to add for others, when i use pickletype in sqlalchemy, when i added the column through sqlite3 i had to use "alter table ... add column .. text".  maybe this is obvious in retrospect as sqlite3 has no column type 'pickletype'

Comment: As of SQLAlchemy version 0.7, there is no longer a `mutable` parameter on PickleType. This was removed for performance reasons, and a new mutability strategy was introduced instead. See (in the version 0.9 docs) http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/mutable.html

Comment: This does **not** work on Python 3.6 and never should've worked with earlier versions. Pickle's `dumps()` is not compatible with json's `dumps()`, as the former takes a protocol argument and the latter does not. On 3.5 and earlier Pythons, this would cause the value of `skip_keys` to be set to the protocol number.

Answer (score 8):

SQLAlchemy has a built-in JSON type that you can use:

```
attributes = Column(JSON)
```

Comment: The problem with the simple JSON type is that it is not mutable. You can only add or delete a row with it.

Comment: `Column("attributes", MutableDict.as_mutable(JSON))`

Comment: @IgorJerosimić winning answer! Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to map a 1-N **relation** and map it as `dict` rather then `list`, then read [Custom Dictionary-Based Collections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/collections.html#custom-dictionary-based-collections)

But if you mean a **field**, then what you can do it to have a DB field of type string, which is mapped to your Python object. But on the same python object you provide a property which will be kind-of proxy for this mapped string field of type dict().
Code example (not tested):

```
class MyObject(object):
    # fields (mapped automatically by sqlalchemy using mapper(...)
    MyFieldAsString = None

    def _get_MyFieldAsDict(self):
        if self.MyFieldAsString:
            return eval(self.MyFieldAsString)
        else:
            return {} # be careful with None and empty dict

    def _set_MyFieldAsDict(self, value):
        if value:
            self.MyFieldAsString = str(value)
        else:
            self.MyFieldAsString = None

    MyFieldAsDict = property(_get_MyFieldAsDict, _set_MyFieldAsDict)
```

Comment: Note that SQLAlchemy won't see you modifying the contents of the dict, so any changes you make to a dict once it has been set will not be persisted.

Comment: Your first link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply save() method to save dicts in sqlalchemy

For example

```
class SomeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'the_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    baked = Column(String, nullable=True)
    spam = Column(String, nullable=True)

s = {'baked': 'beans', 'spam': 'ham'})
SomeModel(**s).save()
```