# sending data in dictionary in database using python

Tags: python, sql, wxpython, sqlalchemy

I have an application I am building using wxpython with postgresql as my database. I don't know what is the right approach to send the data from GUI to the database but what I am doing is storing the GUI(txtctrl) output in dictionary and trying to send it to postgresql. My question is: Is there any way to send the data to the database using sqlalchemy where dictionary keys acts as the column_fields and dictionary-values as its values.Is there more elegant way to do the data-communication between GUI and database?

Comment: It seems similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378325/python-dicts-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: I do something like this in the following article: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/. It might help you figure out an approach of your own.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: I am fan of yours tutorial and follow it quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are using `declaratives` in sqlalchemy, and your object name is Object, you can use:

```
# I suppose you already have your session somehow...
# If you want to add it to the database
# Assuming you did not change the __init__ method
obj = Object(**data_dictionary_with_keys_matching_column_names)
session.add(obj)

# If you want to issue an update
# obj is already there somehow...
for k, v in data_dictionary_with_keys_matching_column_names.iterkeys():
    setattr(obj, k, v)

session.commit()
```

That's only if you are using the ORM and declarative. (You mentioned sqlalchemy, so I guess it does not change if it's postgresql or another one)

**EDIT**: I think you are going for the right approach, just make sure you use `wx.Validator`s for your forms and store in a dictionary the data, it's very practical.